# Returning a Promise from PromiseKit/Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, promise, alamofire, promisekit

I'm trying to do this seemingly trivial thing:

```
static func list() -> Promise<[Activity]> {
    let endpoint = "\(self.baseUrl)/v1/activities"

    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        self.fetchHeaders { (headers) in
            return Alamofire.request(
                endpoint,
                method: .get,
                parameters: nil,
                encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
                headers: headers
            ).validate().responseJSON().then() { response in
                guard let json = response as? JSON else {
                    reject(ActivityError.parse("Malformed JSON"))
                }

                guard let jsonActivities = json["activities"] as? [JSON] else {
                    reject(ActivityError.parse("Missing field"))
                }

                var activities: [Activity] = []

                for jsonActivity in jsonActivities {
                    guard let activity = Activity(json: jsonActivity) else {
                        reject(ActivityError.parse("Unable to parse an Activity object"))
                    }

                    activities.append(activity)
                }

                fulfill(activities)
            }.catch { error in
                reject(ActivityError.network("HTTP response failure"))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the compiler (rightfully) complains that:

> 'guard' body may not fall through, consider using 'return' or 'break'
>   to exit the scope

I understand I need to *return* a Promise here. I just can't figure out what exactly to put below the reject() and fulfill() calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with `reject` or `fulfill` calls. The issue is that after you `reject` in your `guard` statement, you also have to `return` to exit the closure:

```
guard let json = response as? JSON else {
    reject(ActivityError.parse("Malformed JSON"))
    return
}

guard let jsonActivities = json["activities"] as? [JSON] else {
    reject(ActivityError.parse("Missing field"))
    return
}
```

The key point is that you do not want to conflate the promise that is returned by this method (which is later satisfied by `fulfill` or `reject`), with the fact that within this closure, you have to immediately exit the closure with a `return` in the `guard` clause.

---

I cannot reproduce this issue with your code (because you haven't provided a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and there are references here that I cannot resolve). But here is a simplified rendition of your code illustrating the use of `guard`:

So, if not using PromiseKit/Alamofire, you can do:

```
func list() -> Promise<[String: Any]> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        Alamofire.request(url)
            .validate()
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let json):
                    guard let dictionary = json as? [String: Any] else {
                        reject(ActivityError.malformed("not a dictionary"))
                        return
                    }
                    fulfill(dictionary)
                case .failure(let error):
                    reject(error)
                }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you are returning a `Promise`, but inside the Alamofire closure, you simply are exiting your `guard` statement.

---

If you're using PromiseKit/Alamofire and call `then`, you presumably want to create a promise that it can return, such as:

```
func list() -> Promise<String> {
    return Alamofire.request(endPoint)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON()
        .then { value in
            return Promise { fulfill, reject in
                guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any], let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else {
                    reject(ActivityError.malformed("not dictionary"))
                    return
                }

                fulfill(name)
            }
    }
}
```

Or if that's too hairy, you can pull out that parsing of the `value`:

```
func list() -> Promise<String> {
    return Alamofire.request(endPoint)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON()
        .then { value in
            self.parse(value)
    }
}

func parse(_ value: Any) -> Promise<String> {
    return Promise { fulfill, reject in
        guard let dictionary = value as? [String: Any], let name = dictionary["name"] as? String else {
            reject(ActivityError.malformed("not dictionary"))
            return
        }

        fulfill(name)
    }
}
```

But, either way, even when using PromiseKit/Alamofire, you still just `return` within the `guard` clause.

Comment: That won't work, I actually need to return a Promise in there. Returning void won't build.

Comment: I've tried it. Observe that I'm using PromiseKit/Alamofire and the HTTP response comes back in a promise then(), which can't just return a Void. It needs to return a Promise.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a few more examples (which are tested and work). I'm having trouble helping you diagnose your code as I don't know what some of these routines do. If you're still having troubles, please update your question with a [complete, simple, standalone, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).